# How to use `typeof` to get the type of a generic function?

Tags: typescript, tsx

Is there a way to use `typeof` to get the return type of a generic function?

Given:

```
function SomeGeneric<ItemT>(a: ItemT) {
  return {
     value: a
  }
}
```

I want to get the return type of the function.

I first assumed that `typeof` should provide a generic type, but it does not. When using `SomeReturn<SomeItem>` from the following it complains that `SomeReturn` is not a generic type.

```
type SomeReturn = ReturnType<typeof SomeGeneric>
```

So I tried typing this, but I can't find a syntax that works within a TSX file.

```
type SomeReturn<ItemT> = ReturnType<typeof SomeGeneric<ItemT>>
```

Is there some way to get the return type of a generic function?  Note, in my code the return type is more complex and I'd really like to avoid explicitly typing it.

Comment: It's important to note the the *type* of the function is not generic.  `type FuncType = typeof SomeGeneric = <ItemT>(a: ItemT) => { value: ItemT; }`.  So you can't do `typeof SomeGeneric<ItemT>`.

Comment: I thought maybe this would work `type SomeReturn<T> = FuncType extends (a: T) => infer R ? R : never;` but it doesn't. I'm still getting `unknown`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer really depends on your specific use case - in particular the kind of thing(s) your function would return.

The [`typeof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) JavaScript operator returns a string that indicates the *primitive* type, such as "string" or "number", which I assume is not what you're after.

However there's another operator, [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof), that could potentially fit your use case: it's a predicate operator that tests whether the `prototype` property of a variable's constructor appears anywhere in the prototype chain of an object or class. In other words, it lets you check (for example) that the `duck` on the left is in fact an instance of `Duck`:

```js
duck = new Duck();

console.log(typeof duck) // "object"
console.log(duck instanceof Duck) // true
console.log(duck instanceof Object) // true
```

---

Again, the actual answer heavily depends on your use case, but ideally you should be able to use `instanceof`, or `typeof`, or both, to write a function that returns, perhaps as a string, the exact value type you're expecting.

---

A honorable mention is JavaScript's [`in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) operator, which you can use in TypeScript's [guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types).

It works by testing to see if the specified property is in the specified object or its prototype chain. This is known as Duck Typing (If it looks like a duck, swims like a duck, and quacks like a duck, then it probably *is* a duck).

The question you need to ask yourself is, *why* do I need to know the return type of the function? What am I going to do with it? Is there another way?

If what you ultimately need to do with the type is call a function on it that you know is going to be present only if an object is of that particular type, guards may come in handy.

Comment: I need specifically as noted, to get the `SomeReturn` type as a generic type that is the return type of the function. I need to use this as `SomeReturn<SomeType>` in other locations.  `SomeGeneric` creates an object I pass around and use in other functions.